# Having trouble parsing a date in my Android app

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which is trying (and failing) to parse a date in the following format: Fri, 22 Jul 2011 04:14:43 -0700

The code I'm using to try and parse it is as follows:

```
Calendar pubDate = Calendar.getInstance();
pubDate.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat().parse(dateString));
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Fri, 22 Jul 2011 04:14:43 -0700
```

I have absolutely no control over the date data or it's format. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date's always going to be in that format, you could try passing a pattern to SimpleDateFormat rather than using the default constructer:

```
pubDate.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(dateString));
```

Comment: Brilliant - that did it! I did wonder if it was something like that - but had no idea what the format string would look like. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for the full range of date formatting options, and please mark the question as answered :)

Comment: Thanks again - it is now marked answered.  I did try earlier, but was told I had to wait.  It's done now.